# How can I filter objects using django views?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am using this generic view and I would like to filter the campaign_type's for only certain types. 
I was trying to use queryset= CampaignType.objects.filter(type='social') but it doesn't work. Any Clue ?
Notice that the filter is for a manytomany relation with CampaignType and my model is Campaign.

```
 class CCtypeUpdate(generic.UpdateView):
     model = Campaign
     fields = ['campaign_type']
     template_name = 'campaign/campaign.html'
     success_url = '../../'
```

Comment: update view is used for one object.So using filter what you are trying to ?

Comment: I got two models Campaign and CampaignType So I want to update/add to Campaign certain Types I don't want to display all

Comment: can you post complete `CCtypeUpdate` so that everyone can know whether you used any forms

Comment: well that is all  `CCtypeUpdate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
class CCtypeUpdate(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Campaign
    fields = ['campaign_type']
    ......
    #rest of your code 
    def get_form(self, form_class=None):    
        form = super(CCtypeUpdate, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.fields["campaign_type"].queryset = CampaignType.objects.filter(type='social')
        return form
```